# Android Analyze APK

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, apk

I'm developing an Android app with Xamarin.Android.
I would like to analyze my APK and see it's size and how much each element takes up.
I understand there is an APK Analyzer in Android Studio. However, my project isn't in Java.
Is there a way to analyze my APK without opening the project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open any project in Android Studio to access the APK Analyzer - you will be given a prompt to select your APK from the filesystem.

If you need to, just create a sample/dummy project using Android Studio's new project wizard. Then once the project is opened, navigate to Build -> Analyze APK